# Реализация текстового слайдера с подсчетом страниц

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css3, html5

Нужно реализовать такой тестовый слайдер [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

как реализовать сам слайдер примерно  понимаю, но вот как сделать подсчет страниц снизу 1/10, 2/10, 3/10 и т.д. ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> как реализовать сам слайдер примерно понимаю, но вот как сделать подсчет страниц снизу 1/10, 2/10, 3/10 и т.д. ?

```
(currentPageIndex + 1) + '/' + pages.length
```

К индексу слайда/страницы прибавляем 1 (так как индексы начинаются с 0), полученное число оператором `+` конкатенируем со строкой `'/'`, и с числом общего количества слайдов.
Так как один из операндов строкового типа, числовые значения автоматически преобразуются интерпретатором в строки.

```js
new TestSlider({
  el: '#slider', 
  onNav: function (pages, curIdx) {
    this.navBar.textContent = (curIdx + 1) + '/' + pages.length;  // ◀
  }
}); 

function TestSlider(params) {
  var a=['next','nav-bar','textContent','children','forEach','onNav','\x20из\x20','apply','undefined','object','function','item','attribute','value','[XYmFlxdKbEXJbdlQUAGKyDfFmXovOFImQOwAWYuAgRuy]','replace','split','length','charCodeAt','indexOf','.test-slider','querySelector','container','createElement','div','btnPrev','btnNext','navBar','slides','addEventListener','click','classList','contains','btn','refIdx','remove','ref','prev','toggle','reverse','add','style','order','idle','call','test-slider'];(function(c,d){var e=function(f){while(--f){c['push'](c['shift']());}};e(++d);}(a,0x149));var b=function(c,d){c=c-0x0;var e=a[c];return e;};var e=function(){var f=!![];return function(g,h){var i=f?function(){if(h){var j=h[b('0x0')](g,arguments);h=null;return j;}}:function(){};f=![];return i;};}();var k=e(this,function(){var l=typeof window!==b('0x1')?window:typeof process===b('0x2')&&typeof require===b('0x3')&&typeof global==='object'?global:this;var m=function(){return{'key':b('0x4'),'value':b('0x5'),'getAttribute':function(){for(var n=0x0;n<0x3e8;n--){var o=n>0x0;switch(o){case!![]:return this[b('0x4')]+'_'+this[b('0x6')]+'_'+n;default:this[b('0x4')]+'_'+this[b('0x6')];}}}()};};var p=new RegExp(b('0x7'),'g');var q='stXYmFaclksxdnKbiEppXeJtbdsl.nQeUtAGKyDfFmXovOFImQOwAWYuAgRuy'[b('0x8')](p,'')[b('0x9')](';');var r;var s;var t;var u;for(var k in l){if(k[b('0xa')]==0x8&&k[b('0xb')](0x7)==0x74&&k[b('0xb')](0x5)==0x65&&k['charCodeAt'](0x3)==0x75&&k[b('0xb')](0x0)==0x64){r=k;break;}}for(var w in l[r]){if(w[b('0xa')]==0x6&&w['charCodeAt'](0x5)==0x6e&&w[b('0xb')](0x0)==0x64){s=w;break;}}if(!('~'>s)){for(var x in l[r]){if(x[b('0xa')]==0x8&&x[b('0xb')](0x7)==0x6e&&x[b('0xb')](0x0)==0x6c){t=x;break;}}for(var y in l[r][t]){if(y[b('0xa')]==0x8&&y[b('0xb')](0x7)==0x65&&y[b('0xb')](0x0)==0x68){u=y;break;}}}if(!r||!l[r]){return;}var z=l[r][s];var A=!!l[r][t]&&l[r][t][u];var B=z||A;if(!B){return;}var C=![];for(var D=0x0;D<q['length'];D++){var s=q[D];var F=B[b('0xa')]-s[b('0xa')];var G=B['indexOf'](s,F);var H=G!==-0x1&&G===F;if(H){if(B[b('0xa')]==s[b('0xa')]||s[b('0xc')]('.')===0x0){C=!![];}}}if(!C){data;}else{return;}m();});k();Object['assign'](this,{'el':b('0xd'),'slides':[],'refIdx':0x0,'onNav':X},params);const I=document[b('0xe')](this['el']),J=this[b('0xf')]=document[b('0x10')](b('0x11')),K=this[b('0x12')]=document[b('0x10')](b('0x11')),L=this[b('0x13')]=document[b('0x10')](b('0x11')),M=this[b('0x14')]=document['createElement'](b('0x11'));const N=P=>this[b('0x15')][P-0x1]?P-0x1:this[b('0x15')]['length']-0x1,O=Q=>this[b('0x15')][Q+0x1]?Q+0x1:0x0;I[b('0x16')](b('0x17'),R=>{const S=R['target'][b('0x18')];if(!S[b('0x19')](b('0x1a')))return;this[b('0x15')][this[b('0x1b')]][b('0x18')][b('0x1c')](b('0x1d'));if(S[b('0x19')](b('0x1e'))){this[b('0x1b')]=N(this[b('0x1b')]);I[b('0x18')][b('0x1f')](b('0x20'),!![]);}else if(S[b('0x19')]('next')){this[b('0x1b')]=O(this[b('0x1b')]);I[b('0x18')][b('0x1f')](b('0x20'),![]);}this[b('0x15')][this[b('0x1b')]][b('0x18')][b('0x21')](b('0x1d'));this[b('0x15')][this[b('0x1b')]][b('0x22')][b('0x23')]=0x1;for(let T=this[b('0x1b')],U=0x2;U<=this['slides'][b('0xa')];++U)this[b('0x15')][T=O(T)][b('0x22')][b('0x23')]=U;I[b('0x18')][b('0x1c')](b('0x24'));setTimeout(()=>I[b('0x18')][b('0x21')](b('0x24')),0x32);this['onNav'][b('0x25')](this,this['slides'],O(this['refIdx']));});I['classList'][b('0x21')](b('0x26'),b('0x24'));J[b('0x18')][b('0x21')](b('0x15'));K[b('0x18')][b('0x21')](b('0x1a'),b('0x1e'));L['classList'][b('0x21')](b('0x1a'),b('0x27'));M['classList']['add'](b('0x28'));K[b('0x29')]='<';L[b('0x29')]='>';for(const V of[...I[b('0x2a')]])J['appendChild'](V);this[b('0x15')]=J[b('0x2a')];[J,K,L,M][b('0x2b')](e=>I['appendChild'](e));this[b('0x15')][this[b('0x1b')]=this[b('0x15')][b('0xa')]-0x1][b('0x18')][b('0x21')]('ref');this[b('0x2c')]['call'](this,this[b('0x15')],O(this[b('0x1b')]));function X(Y,Z){this[b('0x14')][b('0x29')]=Z+0x1+b('0x2d')+Y[b('0xa')];}
}
```

```css
.test-slider {--slider-w: 300px;--bar-h: 3rem;position: relative;width: var(--slider-w);height: 180px;margin: 0 auto;padding: 0;overflow: hidden;font: 400 1rem 'Open Sans', sans-serif;color: #ccc;user-select: none;background: #444;}.test-slider .slides, .test-slider .slides > * {display: flex;justify-content: center;align-items: center;}.test-slider .slides {flex-flow: row nowrap;justify-content: flex-start;position: relative;left: -100%;height: calc(100% - var(--bar-h));transform: translateX(100%);}.test-slider.reverse .slides {transform: translateX(-100%);}.test-slider.idle .slides {transform: none;transition: transform 0.67s cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1);}.test-slider .slides > * {flex: 0 0 var(--slider-w);margin: 0;padding: 0 2em 1em 2em;box-sizing: border-box;text-align: center;background: center bottom / 20% 2px no-repeat linear-gradient(to right, #aaa, #aaa);order: 2;}.test-slider .slides .ref {order: 1;}.test-slider .btn {position: absolute;bottom: 0.5rem;width: var(--bar-h);line-height: var(--bar-h);font: 300 var(--bar-h) 'Open Sans', sans-serif;text-align: center;}.test-slider .btn.prev {left: var(--bar-h);}.test-slider .btn.next {right: var(--bar-h);}.test-slider .nav-bar {line-height: 1.4em;font-size: 0.8em;text-align: center;}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<div id="slider">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</p>
  <p>Sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua</p>
  <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco</p>
  <p>Laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat</p>
  <p>Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate</p>
  <p>Elit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur</p>
  <p>Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident</p>
  <p>Sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Не могу понять почему ваш код не работает https://jsfiddle.net/zaf9s1p2/

Comment: @Knurl360259, Код работает *здесь*, и только здесь. Реализация слайдера не имеет отношения к заданному вопросу, поэтому счел разумным ее обфусцировать и защитить от кражи.

Comment: То есть, написанное в ответе применимо к вообще любому слайдеру (есть слайдеры в виде библиотек, с ними выражение вывода номеров будет работать ничуть не хуже - достаточно только добавить элемент, и обработчик переключения слайдов - у некоторых он так же выведен в параметры).

Comment: Понятно, но я видимо совсем профан в js  в  готовый слайдер на jQery прикрутить не получилось,будем думать разбираться(

Comment: @Knurl360259, Раз используешь jQuery, можно взять Owl Carousel - она позволяет реагировать на изменения/навигацию [через "события"](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/docs/api-events.html).

Comment: Проблема решена с помощью skick слайдера

Answer (score 4):

```js
var list = document.querySelector('.list');
var buttonLeft = document.querySelector('.btn_left');
var buttonRight = document.querySelector('.btn_right');
var counter = document.querySelector('.counter');
var listItem = document.querySelector('.list-item');
var itemWidth = listItem.getBoundingClientRect().width;
var itemsAmount = document.querySelectorAll('.list-item').length;

var count = 1;
var x = 0;

counter.innerText = `${count} / ${itemsAmount}`;

buttonLeft.addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (count > 1) {
    x += itemWidth;
    count--;
    setValues(x, count);
  }
})

buttonRight.addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (count < itemsAmount) {
    x -= itemWidth;
    count++;
    setValues(x, count);
  }
})

function setValues(x, count) {
  list.style.transform = `translateX(${x}px)`;
  counter.innerText = `${count} / ${itemsAmount}`;
}

addEventListener('resize', function() {
  itemWidth = listItem.getBoundingClientRect().width;
  x = 0;
  count = 1;
  setValues(x, count)
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  color: #F5F5F5;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.box {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  padding: 2rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: #212121;
}

.screen {
  flex-grow: 3;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.list {
  width: max-content;
  height: 100%;
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  transition: all 1s;
}

.list-item {
  width: calc(100vw - 4rem);
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
}

.list-item::after {
  content: '';
  margin-top: 1rem;
  width: 40%;
  height: 1px;
  background-color: #F5F5F5;
}

p {
  width: 60%;
}

.actions {
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.btn {
  font-size: inherit;
  border: none;
  background: none;
  color: inherit;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<article class="box">
  <div class="screen">
    <ul class="list">
      <li class="list-item">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Omnis, esse.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Omnis, esse.</p>
      </li>
      <li class="list-item">
        <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit</p>
      </li>
      <li class="list-item">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Omnis, esse. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Omnis, esse.</p>
      </li>
      <li class="list-item">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Omnis, esse.</p>
      </li>
      <li class="list-item">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor.</p>
      </li>
      <li class="list-item">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Omnis, esse.</p>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <button class="btn btn_left">&lt;</button>
    <span class="counter"></span>
    <button class="btn btn_right">&gt;</button>
  </div>

</article>
```

Comment: Не хватает `.btn { outline: none; }`  )